# free electron gas newtonian fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-state-physics

Is it appropriate to model a metal's free electrons of as a newtonian fluid?
I've seen many approaches doing this but I'm wondering how to justify it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equations for Newtonian fluids are derived from and express conservation of mass, momentum and energy. The quantal nature of the electron fluid does not eliminate these conservation principles. Moreover, the classical equations (continuity equation, Navier-Stokes and energy equation) can be obtained from  the one-particle phase space distribution equation (Boltzmann equation).

A Boltzmann-like transport equation for the one-particle distribution of the quantum electrons as a function of position, momentum and time can be justified for the electron fluid (the relaxation time approximation for electronic transport is based on that). Therefore, from a Boltzmann equation for the quantum electrons it is possible to derive an equation for the velocity field of the electronic fluid which closely mirrors Navier-Stokes.

Comment: Thx for your answer. You said that the energy conservation equation can be derived from BTE. That's exactly what I've been searching for hours now. Can you recommend a textbook/article/whatever where this is demonstrated?

Comment: I do not have immediatley a direct reference.  I have to find it. But in a recent paper like this http://users.ictp.it/~markusm/Papers/Viscosity.pdf you could find some hint (that paper is for specific case of graphene).